# Include external generated resx into Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, localization, resx

I'm translating a large application (solution with several projects containing about 100 forms) in Visual Studio 2012. I created a tool to export RESX files to XLS and create RESX from translated XLS. This app generates a RESX file and places it in the right place in the project folder tree. This is working as expected.

The problem I'm facing is I have to manually right-click every new RESX file and click "Include in project" ("Incluir en el proyecto", sorry I have VS in Spanish).
Is there any automated process that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of full disclosure, I'm the author of TranSolution, a commercial localization tool for Visual Studio (which does what you're asking and much more). It's not clear exactly how you want to do this, but maybe this is what you're after: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.aspx. See the "AddFromFile()" member for instance which my own product relies on but it's not trivial to set all this up though. Moreover, you need to consider updates as well (not just adds), and when doing so, other issues come into play, such as what happens if the ".resx" file is currently loaded in Visual Studio (if you're doing this in an active Visual Studio session you need to refresh it), what happens if it's currently checked out (in a source control package), etc.